# Is there a way to decode Triton/M1 vst PCM samples?

Tags: vst, korg

Is there any way to decode the PCM samples used in either the Triton or M1 VSTs? I'd love to be able to open these in a sampler VST and mess around with them further than is possible within the actual plugins.
I know that the PCM data for the Triton is stored as 3 .bin files in the C:\ProgramData\KORG\TRITON\Resource folder, and the M1 seems to get its data from m1ex.dat in the \KORG\M1 folder, but that’s about it.

Comment: In the United States, attempting to do what you're asking about could be a violation of the DMCA.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to respect the intellectual property rights of the developers of the Triton and M1 plugins, and to ensure that any use of their PCM data is in compliance with the terms of use for these products. Read your license.

If you comply with the license, then you can use tools like MediaInfo and FFmpeg or DAWs like Audacity to read the file properties to figure out the PCM format. If it's one of the standard PCM formats, then you can use FFmpeg, SoX, Audacity or any other tools to convert the PCM data into something that can be imported into your sampler VST.